# Dynamic Join of Tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm trying to figure out the right way to join tables in the given setup:

Table0:
Col1
Col2
Col3
Colx
Coly

Col1-3 are foreign keys for 3 different tables - they may or may not have values (e.g. col1 may be null, or both col 2 and 3 or none).  What I'm trying to do is build a select query that joins to table 1 - 3 if and only if a value exists.

I hope I explained this well.

Comment: Do you mean if all 3 values exist? Because otherwise the behaviour of join will be to join only if the value in the column exist.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't explain it well.  Lets say the 3 columns are "UserID", "ShowID", "LocationID".  For some rows only ShowID will have a value - in this case I want to return values for Show.*, for other rows both LocationID and UserID may have a value (in this case I want the values for Location.* and User.* - I'd expect all the Show.* columns to be null).  A standard join on all the tables will return no rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're just asking for `left join` (or another kind of [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_join)):

```
select table0.*, user.*, show.*
from table0
left join user on user.id=table0.userid
left join show on show.id=table0.showid
```

a typical result might be

```
table0.id  table0.userid  table0.showid  user.id  user.name  show.id  show.name
1          1              NULL           1        Bob        NULL     NULL
2          NULL           1              NULL     NULL       1        Flintstones
```